# Displaying nested anonymous type

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, gridview, ado.net

I'm trying to display a nested anonymous type in a GridView control. But the GridView control displaying only OrderID and OrderDate fields (i.e. it doesn't display nested type).

I'm using the following code:

```
protected void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (EStoreEntities ctx2 = new EStoreEntities())
    {    
        var query = (from o in ctx2.Orders
                     select new 
                     { 
                        o.OrderID, 
                        o.OrderDate,
                        nest_anon = new 
                        { 
                            o.Customer, 
                            o.ShipAddress,
                            o.Status 
                        }
                    });    

        tb2.Text = (query as ObjectQuery).ToTraceString();                 
        gv2.DataSource=query;
        gv2.DataBind();
    }    
}
```

What should I fix in my code to display anonymous and nested anonymous type in my GridView?

Comment: Do you get any errors? Can you show us your GridView markup where you are trying to display the nested object data?

Comment: Why do you need to have it nested? Just flatten the object to display in your grid view.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this as the anonymous type is only valid for the scope in which it is defined - i.e the button click event handler.

You will need to create a real type and then work out how to display that in your grid.

Comment: This is not correct. Anonymous types can be returned and used outside of the method that created them.

Comment: Chris,u meen i should to creat type class that will be suit to my linq results?

Comment: @jason - post an answer explaining how.

Comment: @Michael - yes. While jason *may* be correct it would probably be simpler all round to have a named class to work with.

Comment: Chris,what type have to be a nested anonymus type in the class?is it have to be complex type?